# how to fetch data from multiple edit text in child view of expandable list view?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to fetch edit text data from expandable list view,how can i fetch position also of edit text in activity because i have find ID of Edit text on Adapter?

here is my code

Activity

```
    public class AddNewAddressActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    //

    private RelativeLayout _mainRl = null;
    private RelativeLayout _rlBackToCart  = null;
    private LinearLayout _llPay = null;
    private TextView _tvCart = null;
    private TextView _tvHeader = null;
    private TextView _tvPay = null;
    private TextView _tvfromListTxt = null;
    private TextView _tvnewoneTxt = null;

    private ImageView _addNewAddressBtn = null;
    private TextView _saveAddressBtn = null;

    //tint
    SystemBarTintManager tintManager;
    private RelativeLayout _rlHeader = null;

    //font 
    Typeface font;
    int _maintainAddress = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_new_address_screen);

        _mainRl  =(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainRl);
        _rlBackToCart = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.back_to_cart_rl);
        _llPay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pay_ll);
        _tvCart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cartTxt);
        _tvHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.add_new_address_headertv);
        _tvPay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.payTxt);
        _tvfromListTxt  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fromListTxt);
        _tvnewoneTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.newoneTxt);
        _rlHeader  = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.header_rl);
        _addNewAddressBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add_new_address);
        _saveAddressBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saveAddressBtn);


        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // preparing list data
        //      prepareListData();


        //font
        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"century_gothic.ttf");
        _tvCart.setTypeface(font);
        _tvHeader.setTypeface(font);
        _tvPay.setTypeface(font);
        _tvfromListTxt.setTypeface(font);
        _tvnewoneTxt.setTypeface(font);

        //on click
        _rlBackToCart.setOnClickListener(this);
        _llPay.setOnClickListener(this);
        _addNewAddressBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        _mainRl.setOnClickListener(this);
        _saveAddressBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


        // changestatus bar code
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

            Constant.changeStatusBarColor(AddNewAddressActivity.this);
        }else {


            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)_rlHeader.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(0,28,0,0); 
            _rlHeader.setLayoutParams(params);


            setTranslucentStatus(true);
            tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
            tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
            tintManager.setStatusBarTintResource(R.color.grey);


        }
    }

    private void setTranslucentStatus(boolean on) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Window win = getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = win.getAttributes();
        final int bits = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
        if (on) {
            winParams.flags |= bits;
        } else {
            winParams.flags &= ~bits;
        }
        win.setAttributes(winParams);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left); //for back button
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.back_to_cart_rl:
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left); //for back button
            break;
        case R.id.pay_ll:
            Intent _int = new Intent(AddNewAddressActivity.this, ConfirmOrderActivity.class);
            startActivity(_int);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
            break;
        case R.id.add_new_address:
            if(listDataHeader.size()<5)
            {
                _maintainAddress = _maintainAddress + 1;
                System.out.println("value maintain"+_maintainAddress);
                listDataHeader.add("Address "+_maintainAddress);

                // Adding child data
                List<String> Address1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                Address1.add("");
                Address1.add("");
                Address1.add("");
                Address1.add("");
                Address1.add("");
                Address1.add("");
                Address1.add("");
                Address1.add("");
                Address1.add("");

                int i = _maintainAddress - 1;
                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), Address1); // Header, Child data

                listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(AddNewAddressActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

                // setting list adapter
                expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.mainRl:
            Constant.hideKeyBoard(AddNewAddressActivity.this);
            break;

        case R.id.saveAddressBtn:
            for(int i = 0;i<listDataHeader.size();i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < listDataChild.size(); j++) 
                {

                }

            }

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

on click of saveAddressbutton i want to fetch edit text value of adapter

here is my adapter class

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    Typeface font;
    public static EditText txtListChild = null;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;

    }


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_list_item, null);
        }

        txtListChild = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.expEdt);
        ImageView _expandcountry = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exapandCountry);
        Spinner _spnCountry = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_spinner);
        ArrayList<String> _countyArrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        _countyArrList.add("India");
        _countyArrList.add("USA");
        _countyArrList.add("UAE");
        _countyArrList.add("South Africa");
        ArrayAdapter<String> _colorAdap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_context,
                R.layout.spinner_country, _countyArrList);
        _colorAdap.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_country); 
        _spnCountry.setAdapter(_colorAdap);
        _spnCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                /*if (_transferTo[position].equalsIgnoreCase("Select location")) {
                    _transferToSpinner.setSelection(position);  
                    _location = _transferToSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                } else {
                    _location = _transferToSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    //System.out.println("Selected location" + _location);
                    _transferToSpinner.setSelection(position);
                }*/

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        if(childPosition==0)
        {
            txtListChild.setHint("Name");
            txtListChild.setHintTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            txtListChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            _expandcountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _spnCountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        else if(childPosition==1)
        {
            txtListChild.setHint("Last Name");
            txtListChild.setHintTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            txtListChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            _expandcountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _spnCountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if(childPosition==2)
        {
            txtListChild.setHint("Address Line 1");
            txtListChild.setHintTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            txtListChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            _expandcountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _spnCountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if(childPosition==3)
        {
            txtListChild.setHint("Address Line 2");
            txtListChild.setHintTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            txtListChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            _expandcountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _spnCountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if(childPosition==4)
        {
            txtListChild.setHint("Phone");
            txtListChild.setHintTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            txtListChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            _expandcountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _spnCountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        else if(childPosition==5)
        {
            txtListChild.setHint("City");
            txtListChild.setHintTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            txtListChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            _expandcountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _spnCountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if(childPosition==6)
        {
            txtListChild.setHint("State");
            txtListChild.setHintTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            txtListChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            _expandcountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _spnCountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if(childPosition==7)
        {
            txtListChild.setHint("Zip Code");
            txtListChild.setHintTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            txtListChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            _expandcountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            _spnCountry.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if(childPosition==8)
        {
            txtListChild.setHint("Country");
            txtListChild.setHintTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
            _expandcountry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            _spnCountry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtListChild.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) 
    {
        System.out.println("group position"+groupPosition);
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_list_group, null);
        }
        Typeface.createFromAsset(_context.getAssets(),"century_gothic.ttf");

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addressTxt);
        LinearLayout _panelLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exp_maingrp_rl);
        ImageView _rightIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rightBtn);
        ImageView _openCloseBtn = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.openCloseBtn);


        int panelBackId = isExpanded ?  R.drawable.panel_active_tab: R.drawable.panel_inactive ;
        _panelLayout.setBackgroundResource(panelBackId);


        int textResourceId = isExpanded ? _context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white) : _context.getResources().getColor(R.color.grey) ;
        lblListHeader.setTextColor(textResourceId);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(font);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        int imageResourceId = isExpanded ? R.drawable.right_white : R.drawable.right_black  ;
        _rightIcon.setImageResource(imageResourceId);

        int imageOpenCloseId = isExpanded ? R.drawable.arrow_bottom : R.drawable.forward_iv_black  ;
        _openCloseBtn.setImageResource(imageOpenCloseId);


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I make Edit text as static to access in activity but i can not fetch position of edit text because i am using multiple edit text.

Please Help Me.

suggestions appreciated

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to store data into application class to access on save button.
2. You can create a public method into adapter which will return clicked edit text data.

   ```
   private static ArrayList<String> selectedEditTextData;

   public ArrayList<String> getClickedEditTextData() {
           return selectedEditTextData;
       }
   ```
3. Add clicked edit text data into ArrayList on `getChildView` onClickListner.
4. Make an arraylist into application class to store values of all edit text views, generate getter and setter for it.
5. In Activity after set adapter to list.
6. Get values from `getClickedEditTextData()` into activity and set to global arraylist.
7. Use getArraylist method on save button from application class.

Basically, You can add all entered data into ArrayList separately and getData from it.

Comment: garima :- Your Answer is appreciated, you give me idea to use of arraylist , i am using text watcher to use get edit text data and this value add in hash map and it could be accessible in activity. Thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

i found solution for this question after RND, i hope it will usefull to other developers..

Here my code in adapter

Global Value

```
public static HashMap<String,String>  arrayList = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

after that

```
txtListChild.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("Value : " + childPosition  +txtListChild.getText().toString());
                    name = childPosition+""+txtListChild.getText().toString();
                    if(groupPosition==0)
                    {
                        arrayList.put(String.valueOf(groupPosition),name);
                    }
                    else if(groupPosition==1)
                    {
                        arrayList.put(String.valueOf(groupPosition),name);
                    }
                    else if(groupPosition==2)
                    {
                        arrayList.put(String.valueOf(groupPosition),name);
                    }
                    else if(groupPosition==3)
                    {
                        arrayList.put(String.valueOf(groupPosition),name);
                    }
                    else if(groupPosition==4)
                    {
                        arrayList.put(String.valueOf(groupPosition),name);
                    }

                }
            });
```

On click of Save Button we perform this code

```
case R.id.saveAddressBtn:


            for(Map.Entry m:ExpandableListAdapter.arrayList.entrySet()){  
                System.out.println("Dats in arralist===="+m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());  
            }  

            //end changes

            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this method to find out clicked child edit text position

```
    // Listview on child click listener
                expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        /*
                         * Toast.makeText( getActivity(), listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " : " + listDataChild.get( listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)) .get(childPosition),
                         * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         */
String editTextData = ((EditText)v).getText().toString().trim();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

In this method you can find clicked child position and clicked respected view as edit text and clicked group position also.
If it will help you then accept it!!

Comment: garima :- i have save button in activity and my edit text in adapter then how can i manage activity save button to save all edit text data. if is it possible to sysout of edit text data , it will help me :) i want to click save button not expListview.